# mySQL: YA invalid query syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

this gives me an 'invalid syntax' error.  what's so invalid about it?

```
$companyName = 'big company';
$address1 = 'big bay #8';
$address2 = 'some big warehouse';
$city = 'big city';
$province = 'AB';
$postalCode = 'T1T0N0';
$phone = '0123456789';
$email2 = 'bigKahuna@bigKahuna.edu';

$query = "INSERT INTO clients ";
$query .= "(companyName, address1, address2, city, province, postalCode, phone, email) ";
$query .= "VALUES (". $companyName.",".$address1.",".$address2.",".$city.",".$postalCode.",".$phone.",".$email2.")";

print ($query . "<br><br>");

$result = mysql_query($query, $connexion);

if ($result)
{
    //  Success!
    echo "Fabulous!  check the DB, we did it! :D<br>";
} else {
    //  Fail!
    echo"CRAAAAAPP!  something went wrong.  FIX IT!  :P<br>";
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

i've triple checked the table and it's basically all VARCHAR(50), the names are correct and the sequence is correct (not that bad sequence would break it...).

What am I missing?   ... and NO, connexion is NOT misspelled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of string variables that should be enclosed in single quotes (and properly escaped).

```
query = "INSERT INTO clients ";
$query .= "(companyName, address1, address2, city, province, postalCode, phone, email) ";
$companyName = mysql_real_escape_string($company_name);
//... etc - escape all other variables 
$query .= "VALUES ('". $companyName."',"'.$address1."','".$address2."','".$city."','".$postalCode."','".$phone."','".$email2."')";
```

Comment: yeah.  i just figured that out.  what a stupid mistake.  i used the `'{$var}'` format.  thank you for showing me another method.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting text and not surrounding the text with single quotes. Highly recommend that you change to using a parameterized query.